# why is mstsc crashing when using directX video in browser: TOR, Chrome, et al

Tags: directx, rdp, mstsc

using RDP on windows 10. RDP crashes when rendering directX video in any browser.

exception:
Faulting application name: mstsc.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x57950623
Faulting module name: d3d11.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x6a789089
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000d52df
Faulting process id: 0x2654
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3686b519f9468
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d11.dll
Report Id: 42d43329-f67e-4e1d-a7f8-3fd76e560a47
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

windbg analysis:

FAULTING_IP: 
d3d11!NDXGI::CDevice::SignalSynchronizationObjectCB+8f
00007ffc`e9a852df 8b4608          mov     eax,dword ptr [rsi+8]

ExceptionAddress: 00007ffce9a852df (d3d11!NDXGI::CDevice::SignalSynchronizationObjectCB+0x000000000000008f)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000008
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000008

STACK_TEXT:
000000fc`8c0fd300 00007ffc`ddb43321 : 000001ff`00000000 00000000`f0ef0f20 000002c4`8fbb00c0 000002c4`9a7fca90 : d3d11!NDXGI::CDevice::SignalSynchronizationObjectCB+0x8f
000000fc`8c0fd400 000001ff`00000000 : 00000000`f0ef0f20 000002c4`8fbb00c0 000002c4`9a7fca90 00000000`00000000 : atidxx64+0x63321
000000fc`8c0fd408 00000000`f0ef0f20 : 000002c4`8fbb00c0 000002c4`9a7fca90 00000000`00000000 80004440`00000002 : 0x000001ff`00000000
000000fc`8c0fd410 000002c4`8fbb00c0 : 000002c4`9a7fca90 00000000`00000000 80004440`00000002 00000000`80004440 : 0xf0ef0f20
000000fc`8c0fd418 000002c4`9a7fca90 : 00000000`00000000 80004440`00000002 00000000`80004440 00000000`00000000 : 0x000002c4`8fbb00c0
000000fc`8c0fd420 00000000`00000000 : 80004440`00000002 00000000`80004440 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x000002c4`9a7fca90

Comment: Please review [ask]. Is this a programming question? if so, please post your directX code.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I searched high and low and could not find an answer.  The problem ended up being a bug in my video adapter, I upgraded it on a lark:  AMD FirePro W4100 Graphics Adapter

I upgraded to v21.19.141.0 of the driver. Problem solved.

Maybe this will help someone else.